# How to get right div to align properly with left side div?

Tags: html, css

I have the following html/css:

The left side looks exactly the way I want it, but my problem is KKK is showing up below the left side block. I want them to be inline, but KKK is on the right side. What is wrong with my CSS? Is there a better way to do this?
Basically, I want the outermost parent div to take up 100% of the screen, with the left side having a div consisting of some text separated by a vertical line, and the right side having its own text that is inlined.

```
<div style="display:inline-block;width:100%;">
  <div style="width:100%;">
      <div style="display:block;display:table;">
        <div style="float:left;padding-right:20px;font-size:2.7em;">
          XXX
        </div>
        <div style="float:right;padding-left:20px;border-left:1px gray solid;">
          <div style="font-size:1em;">YYY</div> 
          <div style="font-size:1.8em;">ZZZ</div> 
        </div>      
      </div>
      <div style="float:right;">KKK</div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the following is the solution. Use `display: inline-block;` and `vertical-align: top;`

Don't use  `<div style="display:block;display:table;">`  two display type.

```
<div style="display:inline-block;width:100%;"> 
  <div style="width:100%;">
      <div style="display: inline-block;"> <!-- Here is the change -->
        <div style="float:left;padding-right:20px;font-size:2.7em;">
          XXX
        </div>
        <div style="float:right;padding-left:20px;border-left:1px gray solid;">
          <div style="font-size:1em;">YYY</div> 
          <div style="font-size:1.8em;">ZZZ</div> 
        </div>      
      </div>
      <div style="display: inline-block;float:right;vertical-align: top;">KKK</div> <!-- Here is the change -->

  </div>
</div>
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/us66t90o/1/)**

**Note:** It is bad way to use inline css. Create class and give css to class.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand you correctly, but do you want something like

```
   |yyy
XXX|ZZZ
   |KKK
```

? if so, this worked.

```
<div style="display:inline-block;width:100%;">
  <div style="width:100%;">
      <div style="display:block;display:table;">
        <div style="float:left;padding-right:20px;font-size:2.7em;">
          XXX
        </div>
        <div style="float:right;padding-left:20px;border-left:1px gray solid;">
          <div style="font-size:1em;">YYY</div> 
          <div style="font-size:1.8em;">ZZZ</div>
          <div>KKK</div>
        </div>      
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

if not, can you clarify what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Hi so I read your question and basically you want 'KKK' in same line as your divs so I think you just need to add a float:'left' css in your 3rd div from starting , here is an example :

```

```
        <div style="display:inline-block;  width:100%;">
            <div style="width:100%;">
                <div style="**float:left;**  display:block;   display:table;">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

```
that solves the problem , P.S I personally don't see the reason why you could not have created a separate CSS file and added it to your html using classes.